# AEM - Salesforce Cloud Services

Tags: authentication, salesforce, aem, oauth-2.0

I am setting up a dev org and working on connecting salesforce using the cloud services section as shown here:

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/integration/third-party-services/salesforce.html

I am using a salesforce dev org and a locally hosted aem instance.

I am fairly certain I have the configuration set up right, and I have tested entering incorrect information to each field and got specific error messages that differed from the one I am getting.

When I click 'Connect to Salesforce' I get a login page. After I enter my login information nothing happens when it is supposed to show a conformation page, when I open up the inspector I see that granite is getting the token, but it is not being applied to the resource.

Other times (especially when I refresh) I get an error that reads "Error in Getting Access Token: invalid_grant". But I'm not sure if this has anything to do with my main issue.

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

I was almost exclusively fronend before this, so I don't know where to find the server side error logs, there was one warning logged in the console though, but I doubt it's important:

```
granite.js:226 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
XMLHttpRequest.open @ granite.js:226
send @ jquery.js:9620
ajax @ jquery.js:9210
get @ shared.js:188
load @ shared.js:2738
lazyLoad @ shared.js:2768
getLanguage @ shared.js:2787
locale @ shared.js:2826
Granite.I18n.self.getLocale @ utils.js:892
Granite.I18n.self.getDictionary @ utils.js:934
Granite.I18n.self.get @ utils.js:964
(anonymous) @ widgets.js:88039
```

Comment: Can you check the logs for more error details?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the problem was. I had to change the connected app settings to not only include 'Full Access' but also 'Perform requests on your behalf at any time' and change the refresh token policy to 'Refresh token is valid until revoked'